# Why is ReactJS rendered HTML filled with empty spans?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a `render` method in ReactJS component like this:

```js
render: function() {
  return <div>
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>;
}
```

It ends up rendering some extra spans inside. How can I get rid of these?

Comment: Just tried a jsfiddle, the sample you posted doesn't generate extra spans. Perhaps the code where you noticed this is more complex.

Comment: @Cristik Yes, it was more complex. We have another discussion down below on the answer. I'll update when I run into it again but in the meantime, this did solve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that any space between some block is causing this problem. For example:

```
<div> {foo} </div>
```

Will be rendered into:

```
<div><span/>{foo}<span/></div>
```

It didn't help to use parenthesis to wrap them, maybe because somewhere in my call from a parent component I am not using them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to wrap your return in parens:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>some text here</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Not only is it more readable but it also indicates to ReactJS to ignore the whitespace which allows you to format things as you wish.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change something else? There's no difference in including or excluding extra wrapping parens - it'll transpile to the same JavaScript function calls. If you had some interpolated content which was removed, that would have made the difference, e.g.: http://jsbin.com/fihihiyora/2/edit?html,js,console

Comment: this is a bit weird, but I always add parens anyway hahaha. Like insin are you sure?

Comment: @insin Good point. I'm trying to reproduce it haven't found the right combination yet. But I definitely did observe spurious spans. I'll update when I find it.

Comment: this does not solve, because I have the same issue and it still does this